# "I cannot watch how animals or some living things" Should I use "how"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which sentence is better? Are my comments about "thing" correct?

> I cannot watch how animals or some living things (not thing) suffer, let alone kill or hurt an animal.

> I cannot watch animals or any living things (or "thing" if it's correct) suffer, let alone kill or hurt them.

I would use the second sentence. "How" is unnecessary. I think it should be "any living things" or "thing", but I am not sure.

Comment: What do you think Antonia, and why? We expect you to do a little research before you ask questions.

Comment: I would use the second sentence. "How" is unnecessary. I think it should be "any living things" or "thing".

Comment: Hi please be more specific in your future questions about what you have difficulty with. That way it is easier for us to help you and give you accurate and informative answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot watch how animals or some living things suffer, let alone kill or hurt an animal.

The "how" is definitely unnecessary.  It would be normal to include "how" if you were saying "I don't like how animals suffer".  In this case, though, it doesn't add anything.

> I cannot watch animals or any living thing suffer, let alone kill or hurt an animal.

This wording is much better.

"Things" and "thing" are both correct, although I prefer "thing".

Comment: Because you use **animal/s** twice, it would improve the sentence to write: **I cannot watch animals or any living thing suffer, let alone kill or hurt another animal.**